Is there a way to tell whether an IP address on a system has been assigned via DHCP without using NetworkManager or ResolveCTL?
Back when only ifconfig and route -n and cat /etc/resolv.conf were the only ways to check IP address / Mask / Gateway on a system -- was there a way to determine if these attributes were assigned via DHCP or statically?
I know nmcli connection show will indicate if the ipv4.method is auto. And I know ip addr will list dynamic for DHCP assigned addresses.
But outside of these two, and even before these two packages existed, was it possible to tell?  If so, how?

Sometimes you can tell resolv.conf was automatically generated by dhcp by looking for comments in the file, but this is not standardized in any way.
The most effective way of checking was to see if something like dhcpcd or dhclient was running.  Without these, the system can't renew its ip address on expiration, and likely you will still find one of those even on current systems using network manager.
Of course, even older systems might be using rarp or bootp instead of dhcp, and that does not require a daemon.  (Hopefully nobody uses that anymore.)
Besides the presence of a service to renew the dhcp lease, the only other way to tell would be to look to see if a config file somewhere statically sets the IP address.   How this works has also changed over the years, and you can still manually configure the address from the command line with ifconfig or ip which would neither have a config file nor a dhcp lease renwal service.
So no, outside of network manager, there isn't a way to tell how the network was configured if you can't find the thing that did it by other methods, like checking for a config file or checking for a running service and its config files.   And even these are not reliable, because a service could die, leaving the network configured, or a service could be configured but then the address manually configured separately.
Most likely, the only reliable way is to check for dynamic and valid_lft seconds emitted by ip addr as you already mentioned.  This is probably more accurate than even the nmcli interface, but normally these won't disagree.  I'm not sure how long the kernel has kept those parameters either.
